# Timeline actions not working CS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, timeline

This is quite a simple question. I can create a brand new FLA in CS3 and add

```
trace("hello");
```

to the first frame, run it, and nothing happens. I create the same file with the same frame action in CS4 and "hello" appears in the output window. It's not major because typically I don't write any timeline scripts, but if I wanted to write a quick test, it's ideal not to have to make a separate document class.

Can anyone provide any insight as to why this is failing? Is a reinstall in order? I've found CS4 to be quite unpleasant and would love to stay with 3 unless I need some FP10 functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@josh, no compile errors. I'm not sure I fully understand why, but something in my Actionscript paths was causing the failure. I removed all the paths and then added back the default paths to the library and lo-and-behold, actions are working again.

Answer (score 1):

In publish settings, under the Flash tab, there is an "Omit trace actions" check box, make sure that's not checked. If it's not that, try going under Control > Delete ASO Files, and try again. I hope one of those two help you!

Comment: I wouldn't think there would be any ASO for a brand new file, but I tried that; no dice. "Omit trace actions" was the first thing I checked...also not checked. It's not even just trace though. *No* actions work.

Comment: Here's a fun one: Publishing for FP8 with AS2..."hello" appears. Publishing for FP9 with AS3 ... no actions work. Something there perhaps?

Comment: Very odd indeed, you've stumped me. Looks like a re-install. :(

Answer (score 1):

your comment may suggest that something is failing before it gets to your trace in as3. are there any compile errors?

Josh

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

It turned out, that I was trying to instantiate movie clip that was not exported in first frame and wasn't used anywhere else on stage. The clip was created, but all timeline actions didn't work.

In my case the solution was to export in first frame. Placing clip somewhere on stage should also work.